# Can I add an EventHandler to a String?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, updates

I was just wondering if I could "trigger" something when the value of a variable (like int , string etc.) changes?

Suppose I have a `TextBox tb` which shows the value of `String MyString`. So what I want to do is something like this:

```
MyString.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(UpdateTextBox);

public void UpdateTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
tb.Text = MyString;
}
```

In order to not have to update the textbox in multiple lines.
Is there any way to do this?
Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

A `string` **never changes**. It is immutable (barring evil code that works under the hood). If `MyString` is a *property*, then you could of course have a `MyStringChanged` event, and hook *that* up to the event handler.

```
private string myString;
public string MyString {
    get { return myString; }
    set {
       if(myString != value) {
          myString = value;
          var handler = MyStringChanged;
          if(handler!=null) handler(this,EventArgs.Empty);
       }
    }
}
public event EventHandler MyStringChanged;
```

Comment: +1 for checking of equality before change/raise and avoiding all traps by raising an event (create local copy; check for nullity).

Comment: @Oliver it's almost as though I've done this before ;p Actually, I was being lazy: in production code I'd probably have a `protected virtual OnMyStringChanged` method for that part of it

Answer (score 4):

Values such as `int` and `string` are immutable. They can't change.

Comment: ok, can I define my own "ExtendedString" class and add EventHandler to it?